# Expresso Store Custom Payment Gateway

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, payment-gateway, omnipay, worldpay

I have built a custom payment gateway for worldpay corporate, as expresso store only comes with worldpay business.The user journey works without fault. The user click through from step to step, gets diverted off site to worldpay, completes their payment and then is diverted back based on the `getReturnUrl()`. I then handle the response using the stores payment classes and methods.

The issue I have is that worldpay send a notification of this order, independant from the user journey, in the form of `xml` to a predefined URL within my worldpay account settings. This URL is used in case the user loses connection or in case the payment is pending and they need to send another notification when complete. Please note that this is not treated in the same manner a an automatic response url (which is dynamically created thus having a valid hash to act upon.).

**My question** -
Is there any functionality built into the current store payment omnipay classes to deal with this?
**or**
Do I write/use the script I currently have that is not EE based. If so where would be the best place to store this script and point to it via worldpay, taking into consideration it needs to be able to update the expresso store orders database tables.

Thanks in advance